# How to search a string in a single column (A) in excel using VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I want to change these lines in my excel VBA code to something much faster, instead of looping through all the rows, i did saw examples but could not understand them as i am not a VBA user.

When I used the code in samples (google,this site) I don't see the proper need I want, I want to search column A and if values found return the values in column B next to the searched values, else return empty.

Most of the code I used returned error when not found and some other mysterious behavior.

My current code to search is:

```
Dim k As Integer
For k = 2 To sheet2Counter - 1                      
    Dim tmp As String                      

    tmp = ActiveSheet.Range("A" & k).Value                      
    If tmp = tmpstr Then                      
        tmp = ActiveSheet.Range("B" & k).Value                      
        tmp = Replace(tmp, "Q", "A")                      
        mainstringtopaste = mainstringtopaste + tmp + ","

            Exit For                      
    End If                    
Next k
```

Also let me know if this is a better way or any code that will replace it to be more fast.

Columns in the sheet to be searched are  like:

```
ColumnA        ColumnB
trees          leaves
oranges        fruits
pineapple      fruits
leaves         trees
```

So as my above code, trees should be searched and leaves should be returned...

Thank you

Comment: what values are you looking for in column A, and are you matching whole or part strings etc? I found it hard reading your current code given it all variables.

Comment: @brettdj It one string per cell , so i would say whole string. Also kindly see above i have updated the description . Thank you

Comment: Thanks - does trees occur once or multiple times?

Comment: Values in column are distinct (do not repeat ) ,however they do exit in Column B sometimes.See above.  Thank you

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Below are two methods that are superior to looping. Both handle a "no-find" case.

1. The VBA equivalent of a normal function `VLOOKUP` with error-handling if the variable doesn't exist (`INDEX/MATCH` may be a better route than `VLOOKUP`, ie if your two columns A and B were in reverse order, or were far apart)
2. VBAs `FIND` method (matching a whole string in column A given I use the `xlWhole` argument)

   ```
   Sub Method1()
   Dim strSearch As String
   Dim strOut As String
   Dim bFailed As Boolean

   strSearch = "trees"

   On Error Resume Next
   strOut = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(strSearch, Range("A:B"), 2, False)
   If Err.Number <> 0 Then bFailed = True
   On Error GoTo 0

   If Not bFailed Then
   MsgBox "corresponding value is " & vbNewLine & strOut
   Else
   MsgBox strSearch & " not found"
   End If
   End Sub

   Sub Method2()
       Dim rng1 As Range
       Dim strSearch As String
       strSearch = "trees"
       Set rng1 = Range("A:A").Find(strSearch, , xlValues, xlWhole)
       If Not rng1 Is Nothing Then
           MsgBox "Find has matched " & strSearch & vbNewLine & "corresponding cell is " & rng1.Offset(0, 1)
       Else
           MsgBox strSearch & " not found"
       End If
   End Sub
   ```

Comment: One query  is this line "  Set rng1 = Range("A:A").Find(strSearch, , xlValues, xlWhole)" 

I think this line takes me to the sheet and searching is visible to me i can see the cells getting selected etc, how to hide it ?i mean i am showing my process progress in a textbox but it takes me to the sheet and shows different columns getting selected etc...
Thank you

Comment: @confusedMind Sure ask away. No - there are no `Select` or `Activate` comments in my code, so it won't be doing any highlighting.